# abstract class vs calling base

Tags: c#, class, abstract

I need to give the user some degree of control over a function. So I want to partially implement a class that the user can fully implement. I came up with this solution.

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected void FunctionA()
    {
        // My implementation here
        FunctionB();
    }

    protected abstract void FunctionB();
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void FunctionB()
    {
        // User implementation here
    }
}
```

The other solution is this

```
public class A
{
    protected virtual void FunctionB()
    {
        // My implementation here
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void FunctionB()
    {
        base.FunctionB();
        // User implementation here
    }
}
```

Is there any reason I should use one of these solutions over the other? Does it provide some sort of advantage? Could someone give me some insight on when I should use one solution and not the other?

Comment: The two are not equivalent functionally. One example is the fact that your 2nd solution allows the user to use A's functionality without having a B, while your first doesn't.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your actual use case - what it is you're trying to accomplish here? http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first solution is actually a well known pattern, called the [Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). It's a good approach if you want to make sure the base method is executed (because `FunctionA` might do others things besides calling `FunctionB`).

In the second solution, it becomes possible for the overriding method to not call the base method. Depending on your scenario, it might be appropriate, or not.